# UWP Convert an app service to run in the same process as its host app

Tags: service, uwp

I am following example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/convert-app-service-in-process to convert an app service to run in the same process as its host app.  But Microsoft documentation is getting worse day after day I find it.  The example is missing clear guidance and working example.

I also tried using example from [Create and consume an app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) as a working example and tried to implement changes suggested in the first link above but without success as the link is not clear where to implement OnBackgroundActivated.  That is just an example but the article in general is very vague and obscured.

Has anyone been able to figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an end-to-end sample that uses an in-proc appservice:
https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/SQLServer

If this doesn't help please update the question with the specific problem you are facing with this feature.

Comment: I really appreciate it but can't you guys at Microsoft update your own documentation at the link above to make it clear rather than providing a GitHub project using winforms and SQL server.  It would make much more sense.  Thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: I have reached out to the doc team on this. I agree we should have a dedicated sample for in-proc appservice. I was sharing my sample here, because it utilizes an in-proc appservice, so you can see a working example. The actual purpose of that sample is to demonstrate communication between classic and UWP processes.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. But it is not just missing example, the documentation in general has lots of errors, wrong info, missing info, missing diagrams, missing samples, missing clear requirements, missing depth, misleading or incorrect requirements. Lots of it was fixed recently based on my and perhaps others' comments from few months ago but it is dead-slow-going-nowhere kind of vicious circle. Not sure what happened to great msdn from 10-15 yrs ago.